# How to remove the last line of one table?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

How do I remove the last line of one table. My code is like this.

```
%\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip,skip=0.5\abovecaptionskip]{caption}
%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{verbatim}
\hyphenation{presents}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3pt}
\date{February 2022}
%%% journal %%%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test)}
\begin{tabular}
    {|m{2.3cm}<{\centering}|m{10cm}<{\centering}|}
\hline
Process Operation Type & PLC action  \\
\hline
Robot (Automation) & \begin{enumerate}
\item From 1939, the SS assumed responsibility for “solving” the so-called Jewish Question; after 1941, its leadership planned, coordinated and directed the so-called Final Solution of the Jewish Question. This “solution” was the annihilation of the European Jews, which we now refer to as the Holocaust.
\item  
In 1925, Adolf Hitler, the Führer of the National Socialist German Worker's Party (Nationalsozialistische Deutsche Arbeiterpartei-NSDAP), or Nazi party, established the SS. Subordinated to the chief of staff of the SA (Sturmabteilungen; Assault Detachments), the SS had the following duties: protecting Hitler and other Nazi l
\end{enumerate}  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{label:mapping_rule_examples}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is the table I got. I want to remove the last empty line, as marked in red. Can anybody help me?

[image]

Comment: Note that the example as it sits here does not compile as `H` is not a supported float placement out of the box.

Comment: Plus you have unsupported unicode chars.

Comment: If you have only a single item in the enumeration, do you actually need it?

Comment: Yes, I need it, in fact, I have more than on enumeration. I put this code just to simplify

Comment: The enumerate adds a `\topsep` vertical space at the end, so maybe the easiest is to put `\\[-\topsep]` after the enumerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tabularray (stretch=-1) and enumitem (nosep).

```
    %\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
    \documentclass{article}
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659691/how-to-remove-the-last-line-of-one-table

    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        hlines,vlines,
        colspec={
            Q[m,c,wd=2.3cm]
            Q[m,c,wd=10cm]
        },
        stretch=-1%<--- remove extra space above and below lists with nosep option
        % doc p.51 tabularray
        }
        Process Operation Type & PLC action  \\
        Robot (Automation) & \begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,nosep]
            \item From 1939, the SS assumed responsibility for “solving” the so-called Jewish Question; after 1941, its leadership planned, coordinated and directed the so-called Final Solution of the Jewish Question. This “solution” was the annihilation of the European Jews, which we now refer to as the Holocaust. 
            \item In 1925, Adolf Hitler, the Führer of the National Socialist German Worker's Party (Nationalsozialistische Deutsche Arbeiterpartei-NSDAP), or Nazi party, established the SS. Subordinated to the chief of staff of the SA (Sturmabteilungen; Assault Detachments), the SS had the following duties: protecting Hitler and other Nazi l
            \end{enumerate}%
    \end{tblr}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you load `enumeitem`, you can customise lists. The code below applies `nosep` with additional keys `before=...` and `after=...`. The former makes a list compact and the latter is to add code before and after the list, which in the example run `\vspace{}` to change spacing before and after the list (see [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for more info)

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[skip=0.5\baselineskip,skip=0.5\abovecaptionskip]{caption}
% \usepackage[hyphens]{url}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}   % For customising lists
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % For \Centering and \RaggedRight
% \usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % Adds xmathstrut
% \hyphenation{presents}


\setlength{\textfloatsep}{3pt}
\date{February 2022}
%%% journal %%%


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \setlist[enumerate]{   % Settings for the inner enumerate
    nosep,
    leftmargin=1.5em,
    labelwidth=1em,
    before=\vspace{0.25\baselineskip},
    after=\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip},
  }
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}  % p{#1} for the middletop alignment
  \centering
  \caption{Test}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\Centering}m{2.3cm}|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|C{2.3cm}|}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}Process\newline Operation\newline Type\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{1.2ex}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{>{\Centering}X|}{PLC action} \\
    \hline
    Robot (Automation) & \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      Italy (Italian: Italia [iˈtaːlja] (listen)), officially the Italian Republic or the Republic of Italy[12][13] (Italian: Repubblica Italiana [reˈpubblika itaˈljaːna]),[14][15] is a country that consists of a peninsula delimited by the Alps and several islands surrounding it;[note 1] its territory largely coincides with the homonymous geographical region.[16] Italy is located in the middle of the Mediterranean Sea, in Southern Europe;[17][18][19]
    \item
      Italy (Italian: Italia [iˈtaːlja] (listen)), officially the Italian Republic or the Republic of Italy[12][13] (Italian: Repubblica Italiana [reˈpubblika itaˈljaːna]),[14][15] is a country that consists of a peninsula delimited by the Alps and several islands surrounding it;[note 1] its territory largely coincides with the homonymous geographical region.[16] Italy is located in the middle of the Mediterranean Sea, in Southern Europe;[17][18][19]
    \end{enumerate} \\
    \hline
    Human (Manual) & \begin{enumerate}
    \item
      it is also considered part of Western Europe.[20][note 2] A unitary parliamentary republic with Rome as its capital and largest city, the country covers a total area of 301,230 km2 (116,310 sq mi) and shares land borders with France, Switzerland, Austria, Slovenia and the enclaved microstates of Vatican City and San Marino. Italy has a territorial exclave in Switzerland, Campione. With over 60 million inhabitants,[21] Italy is the third-most populous member state of the European Union.
    \end{enumerate} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{label:mapping_rule_examples}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hacky, but you can add `\vspace{-0.3cm}` before the `\end{enumerate}` on line 31 to remove that space. You can also tweak the exact value you use to get the spacing to be exactly what you want.